# Rounded corners on images with CSS

Tags: css, rounded-corners

Did some investigating in this forum and others but I can't quite figure out what the problem I'm having is..

I set a border-radius on an class within a slider and it starts off with rounded corners, but as each image comes through with the next slide, they revert back to non rounded.

The website in question is here: http://goo.gl/8i8g2

and the promo image section is the one I'm having trouble with..

**Fixed the link**

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me.

Comment: it's not broken, they wouldn't let me put in the IP address so I wrote two instead of 2

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? I see rounded corners on each image in the slider in Firefox 14...

Comment: Works O.K. in IE9 (wow!) and only first image has rounded corners at Chrome (Win7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add:

```
.nivo-slice
{
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
}
```

to your CSS file.

### Edit:

As Edward Ruchevits pointed out below, you may also want to add:

```
-khtml-border-radius:15px;
-o-border-radius:15px;
```

to support other browsers.

And this should work fine in >IE9. You may also want to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to your header.

Comment: That did the trick! Guessing it won't work in IE, but I'm not too fussed

Comment: It should work in IE9. Add this to your header: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` :)

Comment: checked ie8 not checked ie9 yet

Answer (score 0):

By the way, **snuffn**'s answer is not complete, there are two more options: for old IEs and for Linux users.

```
.nivo-slice
{
    behavior: url("border-radius.htc");

       -moz-border-radius: 15px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px; /* Safari and Chrome */
     -khtml-border-radius: 15px; /* Linux browsers */
            border-radius: 15px; /* Opera 10.50, IE and CSS3 */
}
```

To use `behavior`, you'll need to download the appropriate file from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/).

Comment: @Kevin It is needed for IE6, IE7 and IE8, which don't support `border-radius` option. You're having problem with displaying rounded corners in these browsers?

Comment: I know it doesn't support border-radius - I assumed that's what the behaviour was for?

Comment: @Kevin Yes. So, I can't understand how you realized, that it's not working?

Comment: I figured it wasn't working when I added the behaviour then tested it with one of those older browsers... 

Maybe I'm confused - the behaviour adds the rounded corners for older versions of ie correct? Added the behaviour, checked ie8, no dice.

Comment: @Kevin Hm, that's interesting. I'll answer as soon as i'll figure it out.